# How to Run Query on JSON Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4hxqmzjr/) and let me know how I can retrieve the `cost` option of each JSON file and selected item from the list which has equal value?

```js
 var data = {
   "items": [{
     "item": "Item 1",
     "cost": "100"
   }, {
     "item": "Item 2",
     "cost": "200"
   }, {
     "item": "Item 3",
     "cost": "300"
   }, {
     "item": "Item 4",
     "cost": "400"
   }, {
     "item": "Item 5",
     "cost": "500"
   }, {
     "item": "Item 6",
     "cost": "600"
   }]
 };

 $('span').on('click', function() {
   console.info($(this).text());
   var item = $(this).text();
 });
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #888;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 4</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 5</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 6</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list using the json file, adding the id of the list element as the index of the item in the array. So when the event is fired, you can read the event's id and append the corresponding cost.

```
(function() {
   // Loop through the items array
   for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++){
       var item = data.items[i];
       // Add an <li> element for each item, with the ID being the index
       $('ul').append('<li><span id='+ i +'>'+item.item+'</span></li>');
   }
   $('span').on('click', function(e) {
        console.info($(this).text());
        // Use the id to find the corresponding cost from the items array
        $(this).text($(this).text() + ' ' + data.items[this.id].cost);
   });
})();
```

I've edited your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hxqmzjr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

You can map over the json and add it to the list-item. Now, add the value (cost) to the list-item as a data-attribute. You can easily get the value of the item using the `.data()` function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    data.items.map((item) => {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<li class='list-item'><span data-value=" + item.cost + ">" + item.item + "</span></li>"; 
  });

  $( '.list-item span' ).on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('value'));
  });

});
```

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hxqmzjr/4/)

Comment: Wouldn't `forEach()` make more sense than `map()`?

Comment: @neilsimp1 that depends on your preference.